# pros and cons of a variadic function emulation approach

Tags: c, emulation, variadic-functions

I'm working on a platform on which we can compile C code (and other non-C things), but not variadic functions nor va_list's. I would like to emulate this mechanism - with a focus on simplicity/facility of implementation rather than optimum performance. I also want to avoid relying on ABI features, use of `asm()`, etc.

Naively, I was thinking about passing a number of arguments, an array of argument sizes, and an array of argument data (with the latter being either capped-size of dynamically allocated). And, of course, functions for constructing this stuff.

What are the pros and cons of this approach? Say, relative to an approach in which everything is in a single array, perhaps with some kind of null-pointer-termination a-la-argv? Or a proper list of nodes?

Also, am I reinventing the wheel and even the standard varags implementations already satisfy my requirements?

Notes:

- The C variant is more-or-less C99. So no K&R loopholes, and no _Generic from C11.
- It is the "user"'s responsibility to worry about type identification - using a format string, or some other parameters. Just like with the regular variable number of arguments.

Comment: Can you use K&R C?  No function prototypes?  Just declare your functions as `func()`, and define them as `func( int arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, ...)` up to some predefined maximum number of arguments?   That will limit you to `int` or smaller arguments, and if pointers aren't the same size as `int` on your platform that would be a problem.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: No, that stuff doesn't work, probably for the same reason variadic functions don't :-(

Comment: This is weird, the good old `printf` and `scanf` functions have been variadics since the earliest K&R versions. But 2 versions of accessors to variadic arguments have existed: `varargs.h` and `stdargs.h`. Can you confirm that none of both exists on your environment?

Comment: Do you have `_Generic`? Do you have compound literals? You could do like one blob of memory and accumulate arguments. Like `char valist[20]; memcpy(valist, (int[]){1}, sizeof(int)); memcpy(valist+.., (float[]){1.1}, sizeof(float)); printf("%d %f\n", valist)` and then `memcpy` it back in `printf`. To be sure, can you overload preprocessor macros on number of arguments? And, why not tell us what emulation is that, or do you want to only specifically to concentrate on the question "what are the pros and cons of this approach"?

Comment: @KamilCuk: I'm 90% sure I don't have _Generic, but I'll double-check.

Comment: "an array of argument sizes" --> is insufficient.  An `int` and `float` may have the same size yet differ in the mechanics of how emitted code passes `int` vs. `float`.  Receiving code needs an array of _type enumerations_, not an array of _sizes_.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: But you don't get that information when you use a variadic function. See my second note.